# Unable to insert data in OSB reporting table - OFMW 12c

Tags: oracle

Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "UAT_SOAINFRA"."WLI_QS_REPORT_ATTRIBUTE"."MSG_LABELS" (actual: 2053, maximum: 2048)

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. What are you having trouble with? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to trim the column length in SOA_INFRA.WLI_QS_REPORT_ATTRIBUTE table. Or were you able to do something else and resolve it.

Tx,
MS

Comment: I got what you are trying to ask. You have called report publish action somewhere in your osb project which internally does inserting to infra table. you need to trim the request object in body to be less than 2048. hope tht helps.

Comment: Thank you for the comments - I'm from admin team. There are so many osb projects deployed . I'm unable to figure out which osb project is the culprit one.
In the logs - it is not specifying which project it is.

Comment: Nawaz, You need to seacrh for OSB project that has implemented "Report" fucntionality. and then drill down to closest one. Also , in OSB logs you might find the name of service being called.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have tried looking half of the projects for report action but couldn't find anything. Later, I have disabled all the OSB projects from Enterprise Manager - to my surprise those logs are still continuing - same error messages.